# How to set dynamic route for static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently, to serve static files im doing something like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
// then i start the server
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('HTTP Express server listening on port %s', port);
});
```

However, this sets the same directory for that path for every request, under all conditions. What I want to do is something like this that varies the response request to request:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    if (someCondition) {
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
    }
    else {
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/someotherpath'));    
    }
    console.log('HTTP Express server listening on port %s', port);
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Clarification -- is there a reason you do not want both paths available for static files? [Express allows you to use multiple directories](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) so if you wanted to just have both that also could work? Also what is the issue with your code? To me it seems like it could work.

Comment: Your if/else statement would work just fine if that satisfies your needs.  Keep it outside of the listen function though and in with the rest of your configuration.

Comment: i need it to be inside the listen function, because the static files returned will differ request to request.

Comment: @dopatraman please expand on the use case here.  If it's route specific this isn't the way to go, but I'm not seeing the whole picture here.

Comment: based im trying to render a different static html file on a request by request basis. That means if you and i hit the same url, we will see a different static page.

Comment: You can't adjust `express.static` from one request to another.   It's middleware that works on a matching request automatically.  If you want to make static file serving decisions based that varies from request to request, then you will need to write your own middleware to do just that.  That is not what `express.static` does.  The code you've included also looks pretty confusing where you're using a little bit of express, but not other parts of it - very odd.

Answer (score 3):

You do it the other way around you modify url to make your desire effect

```
app.use('/', function(req,res,next){
    if(condition){
        req.url = newURL // add something to lead to different directory
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
// then i start the server
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('HTTP Express server listening on port %s', port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and seems to be the only way to have dynamic routes while still using express.static.

Answer (score 2):

Old question...but this is a quick solution...

If you want to keep all the functionality that comes with [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), then you can just monkey-patch `req.url` (since it's just middleware):

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Dynamic path, but only match asset at specific segment.
app.use('/website/:foo/:bar/:asset', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = req.params.asset;
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});         

// Just the asset.
app.use('/website/*', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = path.basename(req.originalUrl);
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the result of express.static() is a middleware function, so you can call it dynamically with your condition.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (condition) {
        express.static(__dirname + '/public/')(req, res, next);
    } else {
        express.static(__dirname + '/public/someotherpath')(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had that same problem now i fixed it by making a condition just like the below code

```js
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  //check a condition if its false then return
  if(1 !== 1)return
  //After returned all conditions
  next()
}, express.static("public"))
```

And this code checks if 1 is not 1 then wont show the files if 1 is 1 then it shows all public files :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment: you can still do this within the router

```
app.get('/somepath', function(req, res){
    if(req.someCondition){
      res.sendFile('./path/to/appropriate/file.html');
    } else {
      res.sendFile('./path/to/different/file.html');
    }
}
```

Leave `express.static` to serve your common files like js, css, and images.  Send different html files using the `.sendFile()` method.  This avoids having to use the renderer if you prefer not to use something like jade or ejs