# Express dynamic static routes

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var process = require('process');

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));

app.use('/ZTESTSMT',  express.static(__dirname + '/ZTESTSMT/webapp'));
app.use('/', proxy(function(request, response) {
  return 'http://localhost:8000' + request.url
}))

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
app.listen(app.get('port'));
setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit();
}, 100000);
```

Now I want to have it like this. Dynamic paths depending on the URL.

```
var express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var process = require('process');

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));

app.use('$Variable',  express.static(__dirname + '$Variable'));
app.use('/', proxy(function(request, response) {
  return 'http://localhost:8000' + request.url
}))

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
app.listen(app.get('port'));
setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit();
}, 100000);
```

Is this possible?  I have seen the solution of Lamia but I do not use app.get How does it fit in there?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544846/how-to-set-dynamic-route-for-static-files-in-express

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set dynamic route for static files in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544846/how-to-set-dynamic-route-for-static-files-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using a variable like the following,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let path = '/path'
app.get(path,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(__dirname+path);
    res.send('hello');
});

app.listen(3000)
```

then yes, it is possible.